# Python netcdf - convert specified values to NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, nan, netcdf

I'm plotting pcolourmesh of wind data from satellites and from a weather model. The values are all stored in a netcdf file. Below I try to replace values equal to 70 or 0 with NaN, this doesn't give an error but it doesn't create NaNs either, `nozeros` is the same size as the original dataset. I have looked at the data and it does have values ==70 and 0.

```
 import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv as cs
import pandas as pd

ncfile = nc.Dataset('C:\Users\mmso2\Google Drive\ENVI_I-PAC_2007_10_21_21_22_47.nc')
SARwind = ncfile.variables['sar_wind']
ModelWind = ncfile.variables['model_speed']
LON = ncfile.variables['longitude']
LAT = ncfile.variables['latitude']
LandMask = ncfile.variables['mask']

    #clean the data of values = 70
    SARwind_nan = SARwind

    for i in SARwind_nan:
        if i.any() == 70:
            i = np.nan
        elif i.any()==0:
            i = np.nan 

  nozeros=np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(SARwind_nan))
```

Also, I want to convert areas where LandMask >=0 into NaN, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, setting aside the indentation syntax errors.

The code below will do nothing.  What is `i` ? The result is not saved.

```
for i in SARwind_nan:
        if i.any() == 70:
            i = np.nan
            ...
```

Here's an example which should do what you want.

```
SARwind = np.array([
  [1,2,0,-4,-5],
  [6,0,70,-9,-15],
  [10,11,-12,70,-14],
  [0,17,70,-19,-20],
  ], dtype=np.float32)

SARwind_nan =  SARwind.copy()
SARwind_nan[SARwind_nan == 0.0] = np.nan
SARwind_nan[SARwind_nan == 70.0] = np.nan

print SARwind_nan

nozeros=np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(SARwind_nan))
print nozeros
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've set `SARwind_nan = SARwind[:].copy()` as the values are from the netCDF file, it seems to work.